# Authentication error when trying to connect to MongoDB with Moongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to my cloud MongoDB Atlas with `Mongoose v4.9.2`.

Mongo shell works:

`mongo 'mongodb://[user]:[password]@[host]/[database]?replicaSet=[name]&ssl=true&authSource=admin'`

Here, the name of my database is not `admin`, but I am authenticating against the users in admin (a requirement of MongoDB Atlas).

To authenticate the user, it must use `authSource=admin` (which Mongoose supposedly supports in the URI).

However, when I try to connect with mongoose:

`const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://[user]:[password]@[host]/[database]?replicaSet=[name]&ssl=true&authSource=admin');`

I get the following error:

`{ MongoError: authentication fail
    at Function.MongoError.create ...`

My only guess is that `authSource` is not working.

Comment: is there a backslash in the password?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Nope, it's alphanumeric